# SAS identify combinations of two variables using count

Tags: sas, counter

I have the following dataset

```
data input;             
input Row$ A B;       
datalines;              
1 1 2                    
2 1 2                   
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 2 3
6 2 3
7 2 3
8 2 2
9 2 2
10 2 1
;
run;
```

My goal is only to keep records of the first group of data for the variable A. For example I only want records where A=1 and B=2 (lines 1 and 2) and for the next group where A=2 and B=3 and so on...

I tried the following code

```
data input (rename= (count=rank_b));
set input;
  count + 1;
  by A descending B;
  if first.B then count = 1;
run;
```

which just gives the number of observations in A (1 to 4) and B (1 to 6). What I would like is

```
A     B     rank_b rank_b_desired
1     2       1     1
1     2       2     1
1     1       1     2
1     1       2     2
2     3       1     1
2     3       2     1
2     2       1     2
2     2       2     2
2     1       1     3
```

So that I can then eliminate all obs where rank_b_desired does not equal 1.

Comment: You want to keep the first occurence of b=a+1 for each a?

Comment: I would like to keep the maximum value of b for each a. It's just coincidence here that b=a+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag to 1 when you encounter a new value of A, then set it to 0 if B changes. `retain` will preserve the value of the flag when a new line is read from the input.

```
data want;
    set input;
    by A descending B;
    retain flag;
    if first.B then flag = 0;
    if first.A then flag = 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can also be achieved via `proc sql`, with the added benefit that it does not depend on the data being pre sorted.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select *
    from input
    group by A
    having B = max(B)
    order by Row;
quit;
```

Or to match user234821's output:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select 
        *, 
        ifn(B = max(B), 1, 0) as flag
    from input
    group by A
    order by Row;
quit;
```